# Upload 1 file with onchange twice

Tags: javascript

I found 1 but in my application.

I have to send file to server from my page but I can do that twice with the same file.

I have cod something like

```
<div>
  <input type="file" accept=".jpg" id="input" style="display:none" onchange="uploadImage(this)"/>
  <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="bind()">Click here</button> 
</div>

<script>

function bind(){
  document.getElementById('input').click();
}

function uploadImage(el){

  var curFiles = el.files;

  if(curFiles.length != 0) {

    var file = curFiles[0];
    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = function (loadedFile) {
      sentToServer(loadedFile);
    }
   fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }
</script>
```

So, when I press button and choose 1 file, for example, 1.jpg, it uploads. If I again choose it, it wouldn't upload again. But if I choose 2.jpg, new image uploads and sends to the server.

So, what should I do to be possible upload any time my 1.jpg. I need do that if my connection with server lost. But I can`t have another button on my form except that one which choose and send

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is quite typical, after you select the first time the file `1.jpg` in the `<input>` then the second time the change event is not fired again because the input value didn't change!

It's sufficient to reset the value of the input, add somewhere at the end of your handler:
`el.value = null`

```js
function onChange (event) {
  document.body.append('changed')
  event.target.value = null
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="onChange(event)" />
```

Comment: It works, but I do not understand, Why debagger go thhough my function twice? And first method which call my function is Click. So my stack is Click-bind-onchange-uploadImage. The seccond call is Click-bind-onchange-uploadImage-onchange-uploadImage

Comment: mm right, it's due to `event.target.value` that's in fact a change to the input element. Just check in your `onChange` handler if there are files or not, you already do it with `if(curFiles.length != 0) {` so you're fine

Comment: I mean, Why when I select the second time my 1.jpg, in a row, I have double call of my function uploadImage(); How to avoid that?

Comment: mmm I tested both my code and your code + `el.value = null` and actually I don't see the double call on the second upload, can you share the code you're using? Where did you place `el.value = null` in the uploadImage or bind function?

Comment: Ok, I will do that, but maybe on the WeekEnd